# How to debug resque job in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque

How can I debug a resque job in rails application? I just want to write some info in a log file from self.perform function.
I have written this

> system("echo sos >> /home/maruf/Desktop/log.txt")

in self.perform(). But nothing happened. What is the proper way?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Why not use the `Logger` facility?

```
log = Logger.new 'log/resque.log'
log.debug "foo bar"
```

And then `tail -f` your newly generated log in `"#{Rails.root}/log/resque.log'`. **Remember to restart your resque workers as they cache the code and won't pick up changes like the rest of your development environment!**

Comment: I also tried this before but experiences some other problems. Another approach can be found at the blog post http://www.jademind.com/blog/posts/enable-immediate-log-messages-of-resque-workers which shows how to instantly log into a separate log file.

Answer (score 1):

`Rails.logger` should work fine:

```
Rails.logger.debug('foo bar')
```